Scrolling question in SfCalendar .Net Maui

Could you please tell me how to completely disable scrolling in SfCalendar (both vertical and horizontal), I have not found such a solution in the documentation. Thank you very much in advance for the answer............)

You can set the MinimumDate and MaximumDate properties. By setting these two properties, you can restrict the user to a specific date range, effectively disabling scrolling outside that range(the minimum and maximum date range).
calendar.MinimumDate = DateTime.Now;
calendar.MaximumDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(20);

For more details, you can refer to Date Restrictions in .NET MAUI Calendar control

It doesn't work and completely limits my calendar. And I have other functionality to switch months, but I need to block scrolling specifically

@VladyslavMalin May I know what platform you are using? And what do you mean it does not work, can you help explain it?

I'm using .Net Maui. These properties sort of limit and create a specific range from minimum to maximum date. In this case the navigation stops working completely and you can't switch to the next or previous month.
I don't want the navigation to work with the help of the existing arrows, but I don't want the calendar swipe itself to work

Yes, that would completely disable scrolling in SfCalendar (both vertical and horizontal). After checking the docs, I haven't found a workaround to disable the scroll and can switch the month at the same time.
